# TypeScript. Aplicar clase a un solo elemento [angular]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

A ver si alguno me puede ayudar.
Estoy intentando cambiar la clase de un elemento en concreto al hacer click. Tengo varios i (fa-regular fa-star) y quiero que solo en uno de ellos(el clickado) se le añada el fa-solid y se le quite el fa-regular.

```
<article class="task-wrapper" *ngFor="let todo of arrTodos">
              <div class="task-wrapper-input">
                <

i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="task-wrapper-body">
            <div class="task-wrapper-body-title>">
              <p>{{ todo.title }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="task-wrapper-body-info">
              <p>{{ todo.category }}</p>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-circle fa-xs"></i>
              <p>{{ todo.list }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="task-wrapper-favourite">
            <i
              [ngClass]="{ 'fa-solid': fillactive, 'fa-regular': !fillactive }"
              class="fa-regular fa-star"
              id="{{ todo.id }}"
              (click)="addTodoFavourite($event)"
            ></i>
            <i
              class="fa-solid fa-trash"
              id="{{ todo.id }}"
              (click)="deleteTodo($event)"
            ></i>
          </div>
        </article>
```

Con ngClass consigo hacerlo pero claro se cambia la clase en todos los i a la vez. Y añadiendo la clase con document al no renderizar de nuevo no veo cambios. Si renderizo con window.location.reload() la clase se pierde ya que lee de nuevo todos los datos de firebase.

La otra opción que he probado para no usar ngClass:

```
async addTodoFavourite(event: any) {
    //const pId = event.target.id;
    //const favourite = true;
    //console.log(event);
    const fillStart = document.querySelector('.fa-star');
    fillStart?.classList.remove('fa-regular');
    fillStart?.classList.remove('fa-star');
    fillStart?.classList.add('fa-solid');
    fillStart?.classList.add('fa-star');

    window.location.reload();
    //console.log(fillStart);
    this.fillactive = !this.fillactive;
    // try {
    //   const response = await this.todoService.updateTodo(pId, favourite);
    //   // console.log(response);
    // } catch (error) {
    //   console.log(error);
    // }
  }
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes trabajarlo con un map

```
//HTML
<i 
  class="fa-regular fa-star"
  [ngClass]="{ 'fa-solid': iconClass.get(todo.id), 'fa-regular': 
  !iconClass.get(todo.id) }"
  id="{{ todo.id }}"
  (click)="onClick(todo.id)"></i>

//TYPESCRIPT
iconClass = new Map<string, boolean>();

ngOnInit() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrTodos.length; ++i) {
    iconClass.set(arrTodos[i].id, false);
  }
}

onClick(id: string) {
  this.iconClass.set(id, !this.iconClass.get(id));
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar esphinx. He añadido todo tal y como lo mencionas. Pero en el html en iconClass(todo.id) me salta el error: This expression is not callable. Type 'Map<string, boolean'> has not call signatures...

Comment: Tienes razón, he cometido un error de sintaxis, ahí he corregido la respuesta.

Comment: Hola Esphinx, muchas gracias! me ha funcionado tu solución! Lo único que he tenido que modificar el tipo string por any porque me decía que podía ser undefined!